# Getting same person twice in response, how to delete 1 from database...Help really stuck

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have done what some of the poeple have said below but now I am getting an 
 Error Code : 2067 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
                                                                             Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
                                                                                (UNIQUE constraint failed: employees.Employee_number (code 2067))

I get this error on the EMployeeDBHandler at

```
database.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values, 0);
```

I am parsing and storing a web service respone into SQLite database. Everything is loading into the database fine. The issue I am running into is I want to be able to delete 1 of the rows that is the same as another. I made uniqueID so it could store into database.

How would I be able to remove 1 of the records that is the same as another? Then take the one that is still there and remove it to another list? I am making a web call with a employeeNumber and want to place that person tied to that employeeNumber in its own listview while everything else from the response in another list.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mTopList, mDirectReportList;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    private BottomListViewAdapter mBottomListViewAdapter;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    private String startingEmployeeID = startingEmployeeNumber;
    private String table = "employees";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //    mBottomListViewAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mEmployees);
    //    directReportListView.setAdapter(mBottomListViewAdapter);
        getXMLData();

        displayBottomList();

        // displayTopList(startingEmployeeID);

        //displayTopList();


        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);


    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                     dbHandler.addEmployee(e);

                }

                /*mEmployees.clear();
                mEmployees.addAll(employees);*/

                //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        /*mBottomListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayBottomList() {
        EmployeeDBHandler handler = new EmployeeDBHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
        db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + " EQUALS " + "Employee_number" + ");", null);
        Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employees", null);

        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mBottomListCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
    }
}
```

Now the displayBottomList method works if I do not attempt to do the delete query but the problem is the startingEmpoyee has two records and I delete one, and then remove the 1 that stays in the database and move it to its own listView.

This is the error I recieve on the delete query in displayBottomList

Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                    (near "EQUALS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM employees WHERE Employee_number EQUALS Employee_number);)

Is is even possible to delete the duplicate and remove the other row to populate a new listview?

```
public class EmployeeDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OneTeam";
    private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employees";

    //Employee table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";
    private static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE = "ThumbnailData";
    private final static String DB_CLIENTS_ID = "_id";


    public EmployeeDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
            + DB_CLIENTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT"
            + "UNIQUE(" + KEY_ID + ")"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);

        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());


        //Inserting Row
        database.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values, 0);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

    //Get single employee
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Employee employee = null;

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[] {
                KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER, KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{ String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                employee = new Employee(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                        cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                        cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                        cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                        cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                        cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));
            }
        }
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
            return employee;

    }

    //Get All Employees
    public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                employee.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                employee.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                employee.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE)));
                employee.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE)));
                employee.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS)));
                employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                employee.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COST_CENTER)));
                employee.setPayroll_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE)));
                employee.setThumbnailData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        //return employees list
        return employeeList;
    }

    //Get Employee Count
    public int getEmployeeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    //Updating single employee
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());

        return database.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
    }

    //Delete single employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }

    //delete row
    public void delete(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return;
        }
        db.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, "Employee+number = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you inserting duplicate records in the first place ? There are multiple problems with your approach.

Comment: There are 2 records that are the exact same in the web service, but the databaseHandler is creating a uniqueID. I am not able to delete the second record of the same person from the web service. I need to create 2 lists from web service call, 1 is the employee that is showing twice and another with people that come back in a web service from his employeeNumber because I need to populate 2 listViews. 1 for the top person and then the second all the others.

Comment: can you post code for `EmployeeDBHandler ` class

Comment: added the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, If you don't want to insert duplicate entries in your table add `unique` constrain to table like this.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
            + DB_CLIENTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT" +
            + "UNIQUE("+KEY_ID+")"+
          ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
}
```

Then while inserting use `insertWithOnConflict` instead of `insert`.

This will ignore the duplicate entries to be inserted in table.

Secondly , with your current implementation there are following problems :

1. you should call `displayBottomList()` method inside `onResponse` as there would be delay in response and you should populate only after response come.
2. Query  "DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + " EQUALS " + "Employee_number" + ");" will delete all records of table . I don't know why you want to do that.

Comment: I am not seeing the override method for OnSuccess after onResponse.

Comment: ohh, I mean `OnResponse`... I used to use `Retrofit` so got confused. Edited my answer.

Comment: I have updated my onCreate method for database to yours, then changed my database.insert to database.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values, 0); I am not getting a Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. I have updated the code for DBHandler

Comment: in the line with .insertWithOnConflict I am not 100% sure what the 4th param should be. Says it needs to be an int. Do i pass the employee ID i do not want duplicated or the row id?

Comment: I got it, I used the UNIQUE id and then did a replace. In the db I only see the person 1 time now.

Answer (score 0):

There are few unrelated issues with your code. First being, you are making a database query on the UI thread which is a big NO. Try offloading to a background thread. Also your UI data might not get updated once the web service call is done (pointed by one of the other answers). This can be handled in a number of ways. Now coming to your problem of duplicate rows, you can handle it in multiple ways.

1. Ignore the duplicate while inserting. One of the previous answers touched on it. Go through this link  - https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html
   Basically, you can use the ON CONFLICT clause either in your table creation command or on the INSERT command. Either way it will work. Since it looks like you want to ignore the duplicate, use the IGNORE resolution algorithm.
2. Another approach you can use without actually deleting the duplicate is using the GROUP BY clause in your query. This will be easier for you as you don't have to make any changes to your current schema and INSERT command. Just use GROUP BY in your query. Check this link on how to use GROUP BY - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

You have to GROUP BY on your unique key (employee id in your case).

Comment: So should I call the getXMLData() in a background thread? But then wouldn't I have to call that in onCreate as I want this first web service to be called as soon as the app is opened? I thought the Callback with OkHttp3 was on a background thread already. Is this not true?

Comment: Nope. `displayBottomList` should be called on a background thread. May be on an AsyncTask